# Portfolio Slideshow Sliders Behaving Oddly When in jQuery Ui Tabs

Tags: plugins, jquery, gallery, slideshow, jquery-ui

I have a pair of Portfolio Slideshows inside of jQuery UI Tabs. One per tab with each pulling in a different page's gallery. When I switch between tabs the slideshows behave oddly. The main image is shrinking down to about 10% of its width, but keeping its height. When the page first loads, it seems to be working correctly, and this only happens when the second tab is selected.  Once the second tab is selected it will then affect the first tab as well. This can be seen here: [wwnumc.org/2012-nehawka-christmas-program/](http://wwnumc.org/2012-nehawka-christmas-program/).

I've tried several different approaches to try and rule things out.  First being placing the Portfolio Slideshows on the page outside of the jQuery UI Tabs.  Both work correctly when not in Tabs. I see no errors on the page using the console.  I've also checked Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  All three show the same problem.

- WordPress Version: 3.5
- Portfolio Slideshow Version: 1.5.0
- jQuery Version: 1.7.1
- jQuery UI Version: 1.9.2

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The width of the main image div is being reset to `100px`. I don't know why. Look for `portfolio-slideshow` in the Javascript source. Right now, this strikes me as a pure Javascript question, which is off topic here-- [faq]. You may want to post at [so]. I have an account there too.

Comment: I realize the main image div is being reset/resized.  I selected this site rather StackOverflow as I think its more of a WordPress plugin issue that strictly JS.  I could be wrong.  I also have an account there, however that is somewhat irrelevant.  If the answers here don't produce a resolution I'll consider StackOverflow.

Comment: I told you **which** div is being resized, not just that a div was being resized, and what to look for in the source. If you can find the `portfolio-slideshow` in the Javascript source you can make progress. The Javascript might be in a plugin but it is still most like a pure Javascript problem, but maybe not. Again, find the bit of code I asked for and we'll see. I was offering to look at your [so] post if you moved the question there. Isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is causing the problem, you could try adding this to init.js (inside the click function, before fade in):

```
$("#portfolio-slideshow0").css("width","882px");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is bizarre for sure.  Where exactly is the init.js file located?  I don't see it inside the Portfolio Slideshow plugin directory.  I'm certainly willing to try your answer though.  I think I'd need to narrow down the selector a bit more though as there are several `#portfolio-slideshow0` selectors throughout the site.

Comment: it's located at `wp-content/themes/LOP/library/js/init.js`

Comment: Adding it into the click function did not work; however adding `.page-id-356 #portfolio-slideshow0, .page-id-356 #portfolio-slideshow1 {width: 880px!important;}` to the theme stylesheet worked just fine.  Thanks.  I'm accepting your answer.